# perl parse command line options

Tags: perl

I am trying to get parameters from command line and parse it and if the parameters are right call certain functions based on it.I am new to perl, can some one let know how to achieve this

```
 script.pl aviator #switch is valid and should call subroutine aviator()
 script.pl aviator debug #valid switch and should call subroutine aviator_debug
 script.pl admin debug or script.pl debug admin #valid switch and should call subroutine admin_debug()
 script.pl admin   #valid switch and should call subroutine admin()
 script.pl dfsdsd ##invalid switch ,wrong option
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variant 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $command=join(' ',@ARGV);
if ($command eq 'aviator') { &aviator; }
elsif ($command eq 'aviator debug' or $command eq 'debug aviator') { &aviator_debug; }
elsif ($command eq 'admin debug' or $command eq 'debug admin') { &admin_debug; }
elsif ($command eq 'admin') { &admin; }
else {print "invalid option ".$command."\n";exit;}
```

variant 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if (grep /^aviator$/, @ARGV ) {
    if (grep /^debug$/, @ARGV) { &aviator_debug; }
    else { &aviator; }
} elsif (grep /^admin$/, @ARGV ) {
    if (grep /^debug$/, @ARGV) { &admin_debug; }
    else { &admin; }
} else { print "invalid option ".join(' ',@ARGV)."\n";exit;}
exit;
```

variant 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Switch;

switch (join ' ',@ARGV) {
    case 'admin' { &admin();}
    case 'admin debug' { &admin_debug; }
    case 'debug admin' { &admin_debug; }
    case 'aviator' { &aviator; }
    case 'aviator debug' { &aviator_debug; }
    case 'debug aviator' { &aviator_debug; }
    case /.*/ { print "invalid option ".join(' ',@ARGV)."\n";exit; }
}
```

Comment: @ARGV don't have spaces. inifinite spaces automatically removed from it

Comment: How does admin debug or debug admin be taken care of with this case.which is valid....

Comment: @Rajeev this i overclocked. fixed.

Comment: using perl switch would make it look little nicer ;) and for maintainable and easy to change code I wouldn't do the join and deal with each argument separately...

Comment: @Cyber-GuardEnterprise i add variant 2. so do you want?

Comment: Switch.pm was a source filter and therefore shouldn't really be used in production code. It was removed from the Perl core in version 5.14. You should probably look at using given/when (added in Perl 5.10) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are dealing with plain words (and not `--switches`), just look at `@ARGV`, which is an array of the command line options. Applying a simple if/elsif/etc to that data should serve your needs.

(For more complex requirements, I'd suggest the [Getopt::Long::Descriptive](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long::Descriptive) module.)

Answer (score 4):

Having lots of checks against specific strings is a recipe for a maintenance nightmare as your system grows more and more complex. I strongly recommend implementing some kind of dispatch table.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %commands = (
  aviator       => \&aviator,
  aviator_debug => \&aviator_debug,
  admin         => \&admin,
  admin_debug   => \&admin_debug,
  debug_admin   => \&admin_debug,
);

my $command = join '_', @ARGV;

if (exists $commands{$command}) {
  $commands{$command}->();
} else {
  die "Illegal options: @ARGV\n";
}

sub aviator {
  say 'aviator';
}

sub aviator_debug {
  say 'aviator_debug';
}

sub admin {
  say 'admin';
}

sub admin_debug {
  say 'admin debug';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the problem

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.14.0;

my $arg1 = shift;
my $arg2 = shift;

given ($arg1) {
    when ($arg1 eq 'aviator') {say "aviator"}
    when ($arg1 eq 'admin' && !$arg2) {say "admin"}
    when ($arg1 =~ /^admin|debug$/ && $arg2 =~ /^admin|debug$/) {say "admin debug"}
    default {say "error";}
}
```